# plotting larger grid over image2D

Tags: r, matrix, plot, 2d

Does anybody know if there is any easy way to plot a larger grid over an image from image2D?

So I have a matrix of values which I currently plot using the code below:
`image2D(matrix, 0:max(data$y), 0:max(data$x), border = "grey")`

Which produces the following
[image: image of 2D array]

What I want to do is just draw extra grid lines in a darker colour over the top to divide the plot into larger sections at every 10 small grid points so the whole plot will be divided into, in this instance 79 larger grid squares.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah it was me being stupid, I can just use grid 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html